# Can I determine if a stored procedure uses dynamic sql without parsing the definition?

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

Since there seems to be no way to strip the procedure definition from comments  without parsing cf. [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1668/how-can-can-i-get-object-definitions-stripped-of-all-comments), there seem to be no reliably T-SQL query to answer this question.

Or can I get this information from any system view?

cf. [my question about stripping comments](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1668/how-can-can-i-get-object-definitions-stripped-stripped-of-all-comments)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. There is no flag or metadata about "UsesDynamicSQL"

You *have* to search the definition...

There are 2 ways to execute dynamic SQL

- [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)
- `EXEC (..` or `EXECUTE ('`

You can search for the first in sys.sql_modules, the 2nd using LIKE

```
WHERE
   REPLACE(definition, ' ', '') LIKE '%EXEC(%'
   OR
   REPLACE(definition, ' ', '') LIKE '%EXECUTE(%'
   OR
   definition LIKE '%sp[_]executesql%'
```